# Adding color to circular data based on group membership

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to add color to specific points in my circular data based on group membership (I have two groups: one with individuals with a certain medical condition and another group of just healthy controls). I've converted their data from degrees to radians and put it on the plot, but I haven't managed to be able to selectively change the color of the points based on the factor variable I have).

Know that I've loaded library (circular), which doesn't allow me to use ggplot. Here's the syntax I've been working with:

```
plot(bcirc, stack=FALSE, bins=60, shrink= 1, col=w$dx, axes=FALSE, xlab ="Basal sCORT", ylab = "Basal sAA")
```

If you've noticed, I specified the factor variable (which has two levels) in the color section, but it just keeps putting everything in one color. Any suggestions?

Comment: perhaps `col=as.numeric(w$dx)+1` ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems `plot.circular` does not like to assign multiple colours. Here's one potential work-around:

```r
library(circular)

## simulate circular data
bcirc1 <- rvonmises(100, circular(90), 10, control.circular=list(units="degrees"))
bcirc2 <- rvonmises(100, circular(0), 10, control.circular=list(units="degrees"))
bcirc <- c(bcirc1, bcirc2)
dx <- c(rep(1,100),rep(2,100)) 

## start with blank plot, then add group-specific points
plot(bcirc, stack=FALSE, bins=60, shrink= 1, col=NA,
     axes=FALSE, xlab ="Basal sCORT", ylab = "Basal sAA")
points(bcirc[dx==1], col=rgb(1,0,0,0.1), cex=2) # note: a loop would be cleaner if dealing with >2 levels
points(bcirc[dx==2], col=rgb(0,0,1,0.1), cex=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Paul Regular's example, here is a version using the same data where one condition is plotted stacking inwards and the other is plotted stacking outwards.

```
library(circular)

## simulate circular data
bcirc1 <- rvonmises(100, circular(90, units = 'degrees'), 10, control.circular=list(units="degrees"))
bcirc2 <- rvonmises(100, circular(0, units = 'degrees'), 10, control.circular=list(units="degrees"))
bcirc <- data.frame(condition = c(
            rep(1,length(bcirc1)),
            rep(2,length(bcirc2))   ), 
            angles = c(bcirc1,
                    bcirc2) )

## start with blank plot, then add group-specific points
dev.new(); par(mai = c(1, 1, 0.1,0.1))
plot(circular(subset(bcirc, condition == 1)$angles, units = 'degrees'), stack=T, bins=60, shrink= 1, col=1,sep = 0.005, tcl.text = -0.073,#text outside
     axes=T, xlab ="Basal sCORT", ylab = "Basal sAA")
par(new = T)
plot(circular(subset(bcirc, condition == 2)$angles, units = 'degrees'), stack=T, bins=60, shrink= 1.05, col=2,
     sep = -0.005, axes=F)#inner circle, no axes, stacks inwards
```

[image]